# How to dynamic add a column to container.NewGridWithColumns()

Tags: go, fyne

How can I add an extra column to a container.NewGridWithColumns in Go/Fyne?

I have a number of items (containers) rendered in a ColumnGrid. Then via a dialog I want to add an item. The problem is that I can not find a way to extend the original ColumnGrid.

My code:

```
func main() {

    a := app.New()
    w = a.NewWindow("myApp")

    window = container.NewBorder(toolbar(), footer(), nil, nil, content())

    w.SetContent(window)
    w.ShowAndRun()
}


func content() *fyne.Container {

    top := topRow()
    bottom := bottomRow()

    return container.NewGridWithRows(2, top, bottom)
}

var items []*fyne.Container

func bottomRow() *fyne.Container {

    items = nil

    db := sql.NewDB()
    list, err := db.List()
    if err != nil {
        //handle error
    }

    for _, l := range list {
        items = append(items, renderChart(l))
    }

    ct = container.NewGridWithColumns(len(items))

    for _, item := range items {
        ct.Add(item)
    }

    return ct
}

func dlgAdd() {

    entry := widget.NewEntry()
    entry.PlaceHolder = "name"
    e := container.NewGridWithRows(2, entry)

    d := dialog.NewCustomConfirm(
        "Add Item",
        "Add",
        "Cancel",
        e,
        func(v bool) {

            if !v {
                //Cancelled
                return
            }
            if entry.Text == "" {
                //without input 
                return
            }
            //write entry.Text to db
            db := sql.NewDB()
            err := db.AddItem(entry.Text)
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            //report succes
            i := dialog.NewInformation("Succes", fmt.Sprintf("Item %s added", entry.Text), w)
            i.Show()
            i.SetOnClosed(func() {
```

Here is the problem, how to add an extra column to the container ct
and then add the item from the dialog to the new column
This will not work

```
                ct = container.NewGridWithColumns(len(ct.Objects) + 1)
                items = append(items, renderChart(entry.Text))

                for _, item := range items {
                    ct.Add(item)
                }
```

This will also not work

```
        bottomRow()
```

```
            w.Canvas().Refresh(window)
        })
    }, w)
d.Show()
```

```
I am really stuck here.
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution :

```
ct.Add(newObject)
ct.Layout = (container.NewGridWithColumns(len(ct.Objects))).Layout
ct.Refresh()
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me. But I use:
 `ct.Layout = layout.NewGridLayoutWithColumns(len(ct.Objects))`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Container.Add` is the solution, you just needed to save a reference to the `Container` instead of creating a new one.
Depending on the `Layout` it may not always be necessary to change it, for example `GridWithRows(...)` will keep adding columns if the number of items is increased (because the row count is fixed).